# Insert string element in href?

Tags: django

I'm trying to do this :

```
{% for a,b in wireline_list %}
        <a href=b>{{ a }}</a> ->
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't find any way of putting b in href. Because this syntax obviously doesn't work. Any help ?

Edit : Just to precise, a and b both are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax will work for nested lists only.

```
{% for a,b in wireline_list %}
    <a href="{{b}}">{{a}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to use the index in from the for loop then you would want to do this:

```
{% for wire in wireline_list %}
    <a href="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ wire }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```